# How to implement a dynamic chart in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, pie-chart

I am trying to implement with dynamic chart with data from my DB namely the:
- expense.amount
- category.title

I think I need to I am not sure if I need a loop here or a doctrine declaration (I am not even sure my DB is well correlated) but right now this is my controller:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use CMEN\GoogleChartsBundle\GoogleCharts\Charts\PieChart;

class StatsController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/stats", name="stats")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $pieChart = new PieChart();
        $pieChart->getData()->setArrayToDataTable(
            [['Categories', 'Pie expense'],
                ['Category 1',  1],
                ['Category 2',  2],
                ['Category 3',  3],
                ['Category 4',  4],
                ['Category 5',  5]
            ]
        );
        $pieChart->getOptions()->setTitle('My expenses report');
        $pieChart->getOptions()->setHeight(500);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->setWidth(900);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setBold(true);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setColor('#009900');
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setItalic(true);
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setFontName('Arial');
        $pieChart->getOptions()->getTitleTextStyle()->setFontSize(20);

        return $this->render('stats/index.html.twig', array('piechart' => $pieChart));
    }
}
```

and this is my view:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}SIMONE{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">

    {% include 'includes/_navbar.html.twig' %}

    <div id="div_chart"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> {{ gc_draw(piechart, 'div_chart') }} </script>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Everytime I try to enter a dynamic data in my array my chart disappear without much error message.

(see the DB image attached)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem is not related with your chart.

If I understand well you would like to get data from your database then use it inside your chart. You chart code seems very well. Now, you have to get your data from your database.

I suggest you create a new page just trying to get information from your database and try to display it as full text and when your are sure of what you get from the database you can try to use it in your chart.

And for that you probably want to use Doctrine: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html with some code which will look like this :

```
/**
* @Route("/product/{id}", name="product_show")
*/
public function show($id)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Product::class)
        ->find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$id
        );
    }

    return new Response('Check out this great product: '.$product->getName());

    // or render a template
    // in the template, print things with {{ product.name }}
    // return $this->render('product/show.html.twig', ['product' => $product]);
}
```